# Auto Populate values in fields of custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow

I have an `Custom_Object_A__c` which has a look up relation with `Custom_Object_B__c`. 
`Custom_Object_A__c` has a field `NumberS__c (Number(15,0))`.
`Custom_Object_b__c` has a field `parentNumber__c((Number(15,0))`
When i want to create a new record in `Custom_Object_b__c` then i need to autopopulate `parentNumber__c` field with `NumberS__c` value without using URL hack. i tried to implement workflow rule but the field was not auto populating. Could anyone suggest me approach to implement this

Comment: when do you need to populate parentNumber__c? Is it after creation of Custom_Object_A__c record ?

Comment: @sf.dev no when i click on `New` to create a new record in Custom_Object_b__c. Then it must be already prepopulated with Custom_Object_A__c value

Comment: so Custom_Object_A__c is parent and Custom_Object_b__c is child right?

Comment: @sf.dev exactly

Comment: If Custom_Object_A__c  has more than one Custom_Object_b__c related records then what should happen.Does parentNumber__c field has to override everytime new Custom_Object_b__c record is created

Comment: @sf.dev yes it has to

Answer (score 1):

We need to write a trigger to populate the parent field from child. Here is trigger code. Please replace `child__c` with `Custom_Object_b__c` and `parent__c` with `Custom_Object_A__c`.

```
trigger UpdateParentNumber on Child__c (after insert, after update) {   
    Map<ID, Parent__c> parentMap = new Map<ID, Parent__c>(); 
    List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

    for (Child__c childObj : Trigger.new {
        listIds.add(childObj.ParentId);
    }

    parentMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT id, parentNumber__c FROM Parent__c WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

    for (Child__c child: Trigger:new){
        Parent myParent = parentMap.get(child.ParentId);
        myParent.parentNumber__c = child.NumberS__c;
    }

    update myParent.values();
}
```

Comment: you are updating on parent right ? i need to update parent values on child fields

Comment: @Gajini I am updating on parent.according to our chat u said on parent

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with clicks and not code using the new Process Builder interface in Spring '15, https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field value to be populated in the form when you create the child record, workflow field updates and processes won't work for this, as they are executed when the record is saved, not when the New button is clicked.

One option is to use predefined values in a quick action. Create an object-specific action on Custom_object_A__c that creates a Custom_Object_B__c record, and add the fields you want displayed in the form layout. After saving the form, create a predefined value to populate the parentnumber__c field in the form.

Quick actions are only currently available in the Chatter publisher or Salesforce1 at the moment though.

For more information see the Quick Actions Implementation Guide: https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/actions_impl_guide.pdf , particularly the section "Set Predefined Values on Quick Action Fields."